# No Dashboard Report Due to Null data

Tags: csv, jmeter, null

I am using this command on cmd to generate my report:

```
jmeter -n -t C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\WRALoadTest\TestScript.jmx -l C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\WRALoadTest\result.csv -f -e -o C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\WRALoadTest\HTMLReport
```

but i get the error:

An error occurred: Cannot invoke "org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.MapResultData.getResult(String)" because "resultData" is null

And my csv file is empty with the exception of column headings so I guess data isnt being generate in it but what is the reason behind that?

Also tried doing it manually on jmeter and it give the same error.

[Error while producing dashboard report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyBO8.png)

Can anyone tell me what i might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `result.csv` is empty it's absolutely expected that you cannot generate dashboard.

The main question is **why** it's empty, it means that your test failed somewhere somehow, the reasons could be in:

1. If your test relies on a CSV file and uses [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) incorrect path to this file may lead to the whole test failure
2. If your test relies on a [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and the plugin is not installed - you won't be able to run it or even open the test plan in JMeter GUI, if this is the case use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
3. It might be the case that you have [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configured to stop the test after the very first Sampler failure

   [image]

The exact answer lives in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), if anything goes wrong you can always find the reason (or at least extended information) there so check it for any suspicious entries and if you won't be able to figure out the root cause of failure yourself - update your question with the *jmeter.log* file contents

Comment: the path to my CSV file was incorrect + i didnt install any plugins. 
Thank you sm!! Youve been a great help throughout my jmeter testing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error, however it wasn't a CSV issue for me.

Depending on your test and if you're using the -reportatendofloadtests JMeter parameter, you may need to add a tearDown Thread Group and then a JSR223 Sampler to that tearDown.

The Sampler doesn't need to make any requests, for example this code is all that's needed:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
```

This will allow the report to be generated and you won't receive any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if the Specify Thread lifetime checkbox in the Thread Group settings is checked, but the Duration and Startup delay fields are not specified ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy4U6.png)).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).